# Is the "bounds" property in visual basic deprecated?

Tags: vb.net, picturebox, visual-studio-2022, bounds

Its probably right under my nose, but for the life of me I couldnt find anything helpful concerning this: In Visual Studio 2019 I can find and use the .bounds property of a PictureBox. In Visual Studio 2022 **its just not there**. Only the .setBounds method shows up, but thats not helpful.
My question is simple: What is the reason that i cant find it?

Does it have sth to do with

- A newer .NET Version
- Upgrade from VS2019 to VS2022
- Deprecated for some reason
- Or am I just stupid/blind...

And if Im NOT stupid/blind; do I have to manually work around "PictureBox.Bounds.IntersectsWith" if - for example - I want to check for some border collision?

Despite the probable global facepalming it would be much appreciated If someone could answer this;)

Comment: Of course `Bounds` is still there. It's a member of the `Control` class so it is inherited by every control. If you had read the relevant documentation, which you should have done, you'd have seen that it is there. It might have been marked as an advanced member in a newer .NET version and so not displayed by Intellisense by default or something like that, but it's there so you can use it. Just go ahead and do so and it will work.

Comment: I just tested VS 2022 with a VB WinForms project targeting .NET Framework 4.8, .NET 5 and .NET 6 and the `Bounds` property of a `PictureBox` was included in the Intellisense listing in all three cases. I checked the declaration of the property and it's marked as advanced in .NET 4.8 as well, so I'd suggest that you have advanced members displayed by default in VS 2019 but not in VS 2022. I don't know where that option is exactly in the Options dialogue but every VS user should give that dialogue a thorough look over. You should also be able to import settings from old installs.

Comment: In the Options dialogue, there is an option to "Hide advanced members" under 'Text Editor' -> 'All languages' -> 'General' and under 'Text Editor' -> 'Basic' -> 'General' that you presumably have checked. I have it checked too, but I use ReSharper and it overrides default Intellisense.

Comment: *Only the .setBounds method shows up, but that's not helpful*: when you set the `Bounds` property of a Control, it just calls the `SetBounds()` method. So, it's probably useful. -- Yes, VS still hides `Advanced Members` by default when this language is selected. Someone thinks that VB.Net devs are frightened by *advanced* stuff, apparently :) Or is it because of the name of the language?

Comment: @user18387401 and at Jimi: Very much appreciated! One simple click *facepalm* ...                                  Ty for your answers, ofc now everything is working.